Accessing Items Nested in a List, Power Automate Desktop
For context I am trying to make a desktop flow that opens severals Project files, Clicks on the Calendar view, and saves the Calendar view as a PDF for each file.
To do that I have to use some logic and get the name and URL of every file that I have using an HTTP Request which I did.
I now passed that information to a list and am trying iterate over it in a for each loop but am having trouble directly accessing the name and URL field I need to reference. To clarify I need to individually grab the name and URL per file.
They are nested 3 levels deep and the path is List[0][0]
I have Power Fox enabled and have tried using bracket or dot notation but get an error saying I can’t access this field when trying to reach into the list and grab the field I need.
Does anyone have insight into a solution or a better way to go about this issue.
